# Select start page based on button clicked in Google app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm new to Google App Maker. I found it interesting when I came to know about it through Google documentation.

I have created two pages namely logout and login. But whenever I restart app, it will open login page by default. But I would like app to open page based on the button clicked. Like if login button is already clicked then logout page should be opened, even if I reload the page.

This is what happening till now,

By default when I load the app, it login page will open and there is a login button in login page. When I click on login button it will redirect to logout page.

LogOut page contains a confirmation message along with logout button. When I click on logout button, it will redirect to login page.

But the problem is when I click on login button in login page, it redirects to logout page as I would like it to be. But when i reload the page (app is inserted in a Google site) again. It will open login page b default.

Kindly help me with any suggestion to improve my small application and let me grow in Google App Maker :)

Comment: May I inquire why you are working with login/logout pages? App Maker appliations work off of Google logins and are only available to individuals within the same domain as the application is published in. So unless you are using logins to connect to an external service of sorts a login/logout is not required. There is a way to set different startup pages, however there is a hard set startup page and then you could use a user table where the user can select a start page and you can select that start page via the app start up script by doing a query. However this would not work for your purpose.

Comment: I was trying to build login/logout app for my colleagues to keep track of their shift start and end time

Comment: Presumably your table has a StartTime and EndTime field then? If that is the case you could handle this via a single page and using those field times to show/hide elements or setting if conditions in your code to log the appropriate actions.